# await _context. multiple Where data call

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have the following line in my Controller code.

When I load in new data I want to check that if the existing data has l.endDate == endDate then for that list of data check if the dataset name does not have the same first 6 characters, if so set the endDate of the existing data to the new startDate.

I currently have this: which compiles and runs but it doesn't perform the second **Where** call as in the data results when the dataset substrings match on the 1st 6 characters the enddate is still be changed.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file, string datasetId, DateTime startDate)
    {
       var endDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
       await _context.DAreas.Where(l => l.endDate == endDate).Where(l => l.dataset.Substring(0,6) != datasetId.Substring(0,6)).ForEachAsync(l => l.endDate = startDate);
       drArea = new DAreas();
       //load all the data
       await _context.DAreas.AddAsync(drArea);
       await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

If I change code to (add ToList()):

```
await _context.DAreas.Where(l => l.endDate == endDate).ToList().Where(l => l.dataset.Substring(0, 6) != datasetId.Substring(0,6)).ForEachAsync(l => l.endDate = startDate);
```

I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1061  'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for
> 'ForEachAsync' and no accessible extension method 'ForEachAsync'
> accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What do I need to do to this line to get it to run both Where calls and then for all selected data set the l.endDate to the new startDate.

I hope that makes sense to someone, it is a little hard to explain. Sorry I was not sure what to title this question.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: _"but it doesn't perform the second Where call"_ - how do you determine that?

Comment: Your first code example looks syntactically and logically correct, but are you calling `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` anywhere?

Comment: What is that `ForEachAsync`?

Comment: @Alberto https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.foreachasync?view=efcore-6.0

Comment: _"but it doesn't perform the second Where call"_ - +1 to @CodeCaster question. Have you checked the generated SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Use a single `Where` clause.

```
await _context.DAreas
    .Where
    (
        l => l.endDate == endDate
        &&   l.dataset.Substring(0,6) != datasetId.Substring(0,6)
    )
    .ForEachAsync
    (
        l => l.endDate = startDate
    );
```

Or if for some reason you need to perform the string comparison locally:

```
var results = await _context.DAreas.Where( l => l.endDate == endDate ).ToListAsync();

foreach ( var result in results )
{
    if ( result.dataset.Substring(0,6) != dataSetId.Substring(0,6) )
    {
        result.endDate = startDate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `ForEachAsync` is an extension method for `System.Linq.IQueryable<T>`.
If you call `ToList` you get a `List<T>` that doesn't implement `IQueryable<T>`, but only `IEnumerable<T>`.

Use `ToListAsync` to get objects, and then, after you've done the updates, call `SaveChangesAsync`.

**EDIT**: used also `StartWith` function to search for string in dataset.

Something like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file, string datasetId, DateTime startDate)
{
   var endDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
   var stringToSearchFor = datasetId.Substring(0,6);
   var items = await _context.DAreas.Where(l => l.endDate == endDate && l.dataset.StartsWith(stringToSearchFor)).ToListAsync();
   items.ForEach(l => l.endDate = startDate);
   await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Note that the `ForEach` works only for `List<T>`, and you doesn't need to perform it `async` since all objects are in memory.